# WatchKit Blurred Background Image

Tags: ios, xcode, image, watchkit

In a number of watch apps demonstrated by Apple they use a blurred image as the background for the app (similar to the UIEffectView for iPhone). I was wondering how i could achieve this in Xcode?

Should I use an Image as the background with a group on top?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this effect is an only pre made work of art. Sadly you can't have such programmatically made effects. Contextual menus are the only component that runtimely blur the background when it is popped up.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

In document, The UIView is used not used for watchOS.

Comment: I think there is a small typo (**is used not used**) there and and this makes the answer hard to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a UIVisualEffectView or just add a blur effect to a view you already have like so:

```
// Blur Effect
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *bluredEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[bluredEffectView setFrame:YOUR_VIEW.bounds];

[YOUR_VIEW addSubview:bluredEffectView];
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this to a WatchKit App?

Comment: No, you can't add any UIView's to a WatchKit App.